# TFS + separated git server. Is It possible?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to use TFS for working with tasks\bugs\wiki\builds, and not to use  built in git server but to deal with separated git server?

I'm planning to have my own git server and would like to use it.

Does Tfs support this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. TFS can be used with external Git server and you can have work items and builds, release management etc setup in TFS. You can build code from external Git repository from a TFS build definition.

[image]

Comment: We can save user stories, bugs, tasks, setup builds and releases for external repos but as I undestand in this case we loose link between commits and work items?

Comment: @VitalyMosin, indeed! Besides, you also lose the pull request experience, code review flows, which are out of the box for the hosted repositories.